# Yahoo Oauth Login add parameter in oauth_callback

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, yahoo, yahoo-oauth

I want to add GET parameters in [Yahoo Oauth oauth_callback](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-requesttoken.html#) url

Please see the example below, i want the callback go to http://yoursite.com/callback?update instead of http://yoursite.com/callback

But in http://yoursite.com/callback?update, I can not get $_GET['update'] parameter. Please advice

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/
  get_request_token?oauth_nonce=ce2130523f788f313f76314ed3965ea6
  &oauth_timestamp=1202956957
  &oauth_consumer_key=123456891011121314151617181920
  &oauth_signature_method=plaintext
  &oauth_signature=abcdef
  &oauth_version=1.0
  &xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"
  &oauth_callback="http://yoursite.com/callback?update"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should URL encode the `oauth_callback` value as in:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fcallback%3Fupdate
```

Comment: here is the `$_GET` array i got `Array ( [oauth_token] => A=xxxxxxxxxxxx [oauth_token_secret] => xxxxxxxxxxxx  [oauth_expires_in] => 3600 [oauth_session_handle] => xxxxxxxxxxxx  [oauth_authorization_expires_in] => 725788286 [xoauth_yahoo_guid] => xxxxxxxxxxxx  [redirect] => 1 ) ` there is no url insider

Comment: then store the state in a cookie

Comment: The problem is I can not get `state` from the call_back

Comment: that's why you can store it in a cookie before triggering the authorization request so you can avoid having to send it in a parameter

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way to solve this issue? I tried oauth with google and twiiter, both support add parameters in url.

Comment: Yahoo's OAuth 1.0 implementation is not as good... You could switch to OAuth 2.0 and use the `state` parameter in the authorization request. That is returned to the callback URL, I verified that.

Comment: Actually I'm using `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=...` . I think it is OAuth 2.0

Comment: nope, it is the second version of their OAuth 1 implementation; the authorization endpoint for OAuth 2.0 is: `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth`